# How to fine tuning VGG16 with my own layers

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras, transfer-learning, vgg16

I want to maintain the first 4 layers of vgg 16 and add the last layer. I have this example:

```py
vgg16_model = VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top=True)

# (2) remove the top layer
base_model = Model(input=vgg16_model.input, 
                   output=vgg16_model.get_layer("block5_pool").output) #I wanna cut all layers after 'block1_pool'

# (3) attach a new top layer
base_out = base_model.output
base_out = Reshape(25088,)(base_out) 
top_fc1 = Dropout(0.5)(base_out)
top_preds = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(top_fc1)

# (4) freeze weights until the last but one convolution layer (block4_pool)
for layer in base_model.layers[0:4]:
    layer.trainable = False

# (5) create new hybrid model
model = Model(input=base_model.input, output=top_preds)
```

So in this example he is cutting from the 'block5_pool', and I want to cut from 'block1_pool' but if I only change to block1_pool it throws this error:

```
data_format = value.lower()

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

So how could I change it to cut in block1_pool, and then add my own dense layers?

### FULL CODE

```
#import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np

from keras.layers.core import Flatten, Dense, Dropout, Reshape
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, ZeroPadding2D, Dropout
from keras import optimizers
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16

TRAIN_DIR = 'train/'
TEST_DIR = 'test/'
v = 'v/'
BATCH_SIZE = 32
NUM_EPOCHS = 5

def crop_img(img, h, w):
    h_margin = (img.shape[0] - h) // 2 if img.shape[0] > h else 0
    w_margin = (img.shape[1] - w) // 2 if img.shape[1] > w else 0

    crop_img = img[h_margin:h + h_margin,w_margin:w + w_margin,:]

    return crop_img

def subtract_gaussian_blur(img):

    return cv2.addWeighted(img, 4, cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (0, 0), 5), -4, 128)

def ReadImages(Path):
    LabelList = list()
    ImageCV = list()
    classes = ["nonPdr", "pdr"]

    # Get all subdirectories
    FolderList = [f for f in os.listdir(Path) if not f.startswith('.')]
    
    # Loop over each directory
    for File in FolderList:
        for index, Image in enumerate(os.listdir(os.path.join(Path, File))):
            # Convert the path into a file
            ImageCV.append(cv2.resize(cv2.imread(os.path.join(Path, File) + os.path.sep + Image), (224,224)))
            #ImageCV[index]= np.array(ImageCV[index]) / 255.0
            LabelList.append(classes.index(os.path.splitext(File)[0])) 
            
            img_crop = crop_img(ImageCV[index].copy(), 224, 224)
            
            ImageCV[index] = subtract_gaussian_blur(img_crop.copy())
            
    return ImageCV, LabelList


data, labels = ReadImages(TRAIN_DIR)
valid, vlabels = ReadImages(TEST_DIR)

vgg16_model = VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top=True)

# (2) remove the top layer
base_model = Model(input=vgg16_model.input, 
                   output=vgg16_model.get_layer("block1_pool").output)
print(base_model)
# (3) attach a new top layer
base_out = base_model.output
base_out = Reshape(25088,)(base_out)
top_fc1 = Dropout(0.5)(base_out)
# output layer: (None, 5)
top_preds = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(top_fc1)

# (4) freeze weights until the last but one convolution layer (block4_pool)
for layer in base_model.layers[0:4]:
    layer.trainable = False

# (5) create new hybrid model
model = Model(input=base_model.input, output=top_preds)
    
# (6) compile and train the model
sgd = SGD(lr=1e-4, momentum=0.9)
model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

data = np.asarray(data)
valid = np.asarray(valid)

data = data.astype('float32')
valid = valid.astype('float32')

data /= 255
valid /= 255
labels = np.array(labels)

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

# compute quantities required for featurewise normalization
# (std, mean, and principal components if ZCA whitening is applied)
datagen.fit(data)
mean = datagen.mean  
std = datagen.std

print(mean, "mean")
print(std, "std")

es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', verbose=1)

# fits the model on batches with real-time data augmentation:
model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(data, np.array(labels), batch_size=32), 
                    steps_per_epoch=len(data) / 32, epochs=15,
                    validation_data=(valid, np.array(vlabels)),
                    nb_val_samples=72, callbacks=[es])


model.save('model.h5')
```

### FULL ERROR

````
    base_out = Reshape(25088,)(base_out)

    self.target_shape = tuple(target_shape)

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```
````

Comment: Hey what's that value.lower()?

Comment: see my update, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is include Flatten layer to the model:

```
base_out = base_model.output
top_fc1 = Flatten()(base_out)
top_fc2 = Dropout(0.5)(top_fc1)
top_preds = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(top_fc2)
```

Now it works!